# Teaching Assistant Visa under age 26

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas, immigration, uk-visa, skilled-migration

I want to be a teaching assistant in the UK and therefore apply for the skilled worker visa. On the UK website (https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/skilled-worker-visa-eligible-salary-if-youre-under-26-studying-training-or-in-a-postdoctoral-role), it says that my minimum salary would have to be about 10.000 pound per year, as I am under the age of 26. Usually, I would have to earn about 20.000 £. Does anyone have experience with the rules and can tell me if I actually qualify for the skilled worker visa with my salary of 13.000 per year?

I have tried to look it up on the internet, but my employers seems kind of confused about the rules and stated that my salary would not be enough.

Comment: 13,000 > 10,000, sound just OK